# fonts look bolder online than in local

Tags: css, fonts

I'm loading an OTF font in local, and I've just noticed the font looks bolder online than when I was working in local.

Local screenshot :
[image]

Online screenshot :
[image]

What could be the problem ?
I only have OTF for this font because it doesn't exist in woff.

Comment: you can convert your font with onlinefontconverter.com

Comment: I tried your link. But even in Woff it looks exactly the same.

Comment: Do you have another idea of what could explain that?

Comment: Do you have online link?

Comment: Sorry, I left due to some health problem ! Yes I have : yeswebrand.fr

Comment: try setting `font-weight: normal` for the `h1` tag

Comment: because default browser agent stylesheet has font-weight bold for heading tags

Comment: Oh yes, you are right ! So many time I didn't made basic html pages and I forgot something like a reset.css :) That's better !

Comment: Hope your issue solved!